# how to fetch value from one table and insert into second table while inserting data to the second table as backend function. using laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

I have two table, one is `account` and other is `user`.

In `account` table `accountID` is primary key.

uerID is a column in the 'user' table. When i insert `userID` value to `user` table ,the `accountID`value from the `account` table should insert as hidden into the `user' table (column name is accountID itself).Because when we insert userID , we are not giving any option to enter the accountID again. It will automatically taken from the 'account' table. In account table contain single 
data.

```
public function userInsert(Request $request)
{
    $postUser = Input::all();

   $account = Account::select('accountID')->get();

  /*  $data=DB::table('account')
        ->select("accountID"); */

    //insert data into mysql table
    $data =      array('accountID'=>$account['accountID'],
        'userID'=> $postUser['userID']
    );
    //  echo print_r($data);
    $ck = 0;
    $ck = DB::table('user')->Insert($data);
    //echo "Record Added Successfully!";
    $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
    return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);


}
```

above am giving the insertion function for creating new userID

How to write sql query in laravel 5.2 to do this ?

Can anyone please help me responses are appreciable..!

Comment: What do you have written so far?

Comment: i created forms for each page, and done insertion part of account table. and insertion part for user except accountID column in user table. Now i want to insert that accountID , while inserting userID into user table. Because from user form am not inserting accountID, its the unique one and for one company they have only one accountID. so when i create userID, that time accountID should fetch from account table and insert into user table.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code and explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to add the `accountID` to the `user` table. You should be able to insert the `accountID` by simple just adding it to the array...

```
$postUser = Input::all();
$account = Account::select('accountID')->get();

// Add the value of the accountID to the post array
$data = array("accountID" => $account['accountID'],
    "userID"=> $postUser['userID']
);

 //  echo print_r($data);
$ck = 0;
$ck = DB::table('user')->Insert($data);

//echo "Record Added Successfully!";
$name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);
```

Comment: This is a namespace problem (which would have existed in your initial code). Try using `App\Account`.

Comment: when use like this getting error "Undefined index: accountID"

Comment: i added App/Account in my controller, now am getting "Undefined index: accountID"

Comment: public function userInsert(Request $request)
    {
        $postUser = Input::all();
        $account = Account::select('accountID')->get();
      //insert data into mysql table
       
$data =      array("accountID" => $account['accountID'],
            "userID"=> $postUser['userID']
        );
 $ck = 0;
        $ck = DB::table('user')->Insert($data);
         $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);
}

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does you `user` table have `accountID` field?

Comment: Please do not paste your code as a comment. It is hard to read. Instead update your question. Thanks.